# Alternate servlet definition to web.xml?

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets

I am using google app engine, and I define all my servlet paths in web.xml. Is there a way to define these in code instead of xml? I ask because the web.xml file is very verbose and I have many servlets. If I could register the servlets in java code somewhere I can probably shorten things.

Thanks

Comment: There're many frameworks to do so. I guess most popular is Spring MVC

Comment: You can also always implement a dispatcher servlet that will forward to your other servlets according to your coded rules. While being a fan of spring i would try and avoid the overhead of most frameworks unless you have good reasons for it.

Comment: Use a framework, they will solve this and many other problems for you (data binding, API abstraction etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can define a "main" servlet whose job it is to dispatch to other servlets; in your `web.xml`, you would write something like:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mydomain.myapp.Dispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

This would map `/*` (your entire app) to your dispatcher class. You could then register your various servlets with the dispatcher under different paths (e.g. you could use the [Spring DispatcherServlet](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) or your own).